# WCF Service Creation

Tags: wcf

I am following Learning WCF ( by Michele Leroux Bustamante). And I am trying to add a WCF service Template to an existing Class Library Project. According to book it says I should be able to see a file called MyServiceHost along with Service contract and service type files, but in my solution MyServiceHost file is not appearing. I am using VS2010 Express edition. For those who could refer this book for more details, I am working on LAB 2 of chapter 1.

Comment: Did you name the template MyServiceHost?

Comment: @Rakshit: I am not suppose to name the template so. It asks me to name it HelloIndigoService... It lcearly says that WCF service template also generates a helper class for hosting the service, named MyServiceHost, located beneath the service type.

Comment: @Chat I rolled back the change.

Comment: @Chat Are you trying to add a new WCF service template?

Comment: @Rakshit: Yes.. If you can refer this book I am on page 32 of chapter 1. Lab exercise

Comment: @Rakshit: Option that I was talking about comes only under VS 2005. In VS 2010 no such file gets created. I scanned through and got this over internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyServiceHost file appears after adding WCF service template in VS 2005 only. After 2005 no such file comes up while adding WCF service template. in VS2010 only Service contract and service type file generates automatically. I scanned through net and got this answer. I am closing my question.